# What is the correct way to conditionally assign something to a const?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to assign something to a const, depending on what environment variables are set, but I'm not sure what the right way is. Here is what I have:

```
const pool; //Technically this is incorrect right ?

if(process.env.PGUSER){
    pool = new Pool;
}else if(process.env.DATABASE_URL){
    pool = new Pool({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL
    });
}
```

What is the correct way to initially declare pool ?

Comment: You must specify `const` value in the same statement in which it's declared i.e. `const pool = "value"`. But you can do this `const pool = process.env.PGUSER ? new Pool : process.env.DATABASE_URL ?  new Pool({connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL}) : null;`

Comment: Since in this code `pool` might never be assigned anything, it's really not a `const` at all.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const - you have to assign immediately, but it can be an expression (including function call).

Comment: Presumably you'll always want a `pool` instance, is it not really the config here that varies here?

Comment: @James You are right. So how do I assign it?

Comment: @KaizerSozay well really for me, I'd have `Pool` handle a null connection string value which reduces your code to one line e.g. `const pool = new Pool({ connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL || null })` - although I'm not sure what significance `PGUSER` has, is this just a user with no DB connection?

Comment: @KaizerSozay A constant (in its mathematical sense) must have a unique constant value. In your case, Pool seems to have varied value. Maybe using a constant is not appropriate.

Comment: @Techniv Actually const should be appropriate, since once it is set it does not change. Its just that what it is set to varies depending on the environment variables.

Comment: @James node-postgres without any arguments looks for certain environment variables to connect to the database. But in environments like heroku, the connection string details are provided as a uri in a different environment variable, which is why I needed to have both options to seamlessly work between my dev and pro environments...

Comment: @KaizerSozay would the above line not just work in that case? Presumably `Pool` underlying will check if `connectionString` has been set use it, otherwise check environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ternary structure and assign the wanted instance.

```
const pool = process.env.PGUSER
    ? new Pool
    : new Pool({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL
    });
```

Comment: I must point out that it's a different condition. Original is `if(cond){} else if(cond2){}` and this one is `if(cond){} else{}`. You still can use several ternary statements together but this is where it gets unreadable. I suggest using IIFE: `const x = (()=>{ if(cond} return x; else if(cond2) return y})()`

Comment: @Seangle, right. the better was is to check the need for getting an instance with a parameter and take the one without for the rest. for me, it could be questionalble, if no condition fits at least no instance should be created. btw, op could use `let` for later assignment. but anyway op accepts the answer.